# Physical File Provider Returns a 404

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to access a file securely using the `PhysicalFileProvider` I've provided the root path as the path to my local temporary files.

```
public static string BASE_PATH = Path.GetTempPath();
public static string lastSavedFilePath = @"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\MyPicture.png"

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<FileResult> GetFileById(int id)
{
    //provides access to the physical file system, scoping all paths to a directory and its children
    IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(BASE_PATH);
    var fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(lastSavedFilePath);
    var fileStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
    this._contentTypeProvider.TryGetContentType(lastSavedFilePath, out var mimeType);
    return File(fileStream, mimeType, "ProfilePicture.png");
}
```

I'm testing with a file which definetly exists in my local path but I still seem to get a `FileNotFound` Error?  Why am I getting a FileNotFound Error for a file that is a direct child of the BaseDirectory?

Comment: How are you calling that method?

Comment: @PatrickHofman through postman it throws when attempting to create a read stream

Comment: As per the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.ifileprovider.getfileinfo?view=aspnetcore-2.0 you should check for file existance on the `IFileInfo` returned,

Comment: And you are sure the web user has access to the file?

Comment: @PatrickHofman seems to have a point "MyUser\AppData..." shouldnt it just be getting the system temp folder and using that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman good point but then should I expect an authorization exception instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IFileProvider.GetFileInfo()` expects subpath of the file within the root of the File Provider. According to [IFileProvider.GetFileInfo documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.ifileprovider.getfileinfo):

> **subpath** - Relative path that identifies the file.

In your code you pass `lastSavedFilePath` which has the value of absolute path - `@"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\MyPicture.png"`.

To fix the problem you should pass the relative path of the file, e.g.:

```
var fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo("MyPicture.png");
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll check this when I get back to my desk

Comment: Yup that was the issue, I really wish they would have automatically checked for me.